# Trello - Tracking a task and the date it was last completed

Tags: trello

Using Trello, I would like to be able to continuously track the most recent date a task was completed.

I want to be able to track the last time a specific thing was cleaned in our retail store. Each time someone cleans that thing again (completes that task) I want them to be able to click something to indicate it was cleaned, which would then update the date to when it was most recently completed (cleaned).

This serves the dual purpose of seeing which tasks were completed the longest ago, offering a cyclical approach where the most out dated things is focused.

Feels like I might be missing something simple here. Thanks in advance.